# React click handlers and binding this

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component where I am iterating over a list and creating rows. In each row, there is a delete button. When the delete button is clicked, I want to pass a reference to the element in that row.

```
var TagTable = React.createClass({

        onTagDelete: function(tagName) {
            this.props.onTagDelete(tagName);
        },

        render: function () {
            return R.table({className: "bg-box padded"}, [
                R.thead({},
                    R.tr({}, [
                        R.th({}, ""),
                        R.th({}, "Tag"),
                        R.th({}, "Regexes")
                    ])),
                R.tbody({},
                    this.props.tags.map(function (tag) {
                        return R.tr({}, [
                            R.td({}, R.button({onClick: function() {this.onTagDelete(tag.name)}.bind(this), // BIND
                                className: "delete"}, "\u2716")),
                            R.td({key: "name"}, tag.name),
                            R.td({key: "regexes"}, tag.regexes.join(", "))]);
                    }.bind(this))) // BIND
            ])
        }
    }
);
```

So in order to preserve the this-value in the click-handler; I use bind both for the map() and the click-handler.

Is this the proper way to pass arguments to handlers in React or is there a better way?

Comment: This (pun intended) is fine. Other way would be to use a closure `var that = this` and use that in the handler `that.onTagDelete`. Also pass your argument in the binding.

Comment: For what it's worth, people use .bind in nearly all of the components I've seen.  It is just a code style difference.

Comment: `map` takes an optional second parameter that is used as the context for the function call, i.e. what "this" means. You can do `.map(function() { ... }, this)` instead of using `bind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly new to react, but I figured I'd throw this out here to help.

I think you need to change this line,

```
R.td({}, R.button({onClick: function() {this.onTagDelete(tag.name)}.bind(this), // BIND
                            className: "delete"}, "\u2716")),
```

to

```
R.td({}, R.button({onClick: function() {this.onTagDelete.bind(this, tag.name)}, // BIND
                            className: "delete"}, "\u2716")),
```

I'm pretty sure that this should now pass the tag name to the function. Another way of getting data from the clicked subject is through refs, but with lists of items I don't think this works well because of repeated ref names. So I would just do what you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do less verbose:

```
 R.td({}, R.button({onClick: this.onTagDelete.bind(this, tag.name), // BIND
                                className: "delete"}, "\u2716")),
```