# how to pass props to a function from a button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use an event handler to redirect a user to another route in reactJS but I have not figured out how i can pass down it's props to the event handler function.

```
<button onClick={ChallengeActions.OpenChallenge(item.title) }>Start<button>
```

This is what my event listener looks like

```
onOpenChallenge: function(url) {

    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The problem is that the function automatically fires up whenever i load the page instead of waiting for the event handler, I also get the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [React click handlers and binding this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346263/react-click-handlers-and-binding-this)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of the following:

1. event handlers need to be mapped to a function:

```
<button onClick={this.onChallengeButtonClicked}>Start</button>
```

2. You need to tell each button to which item it corresponds to:

```
<button item={item} onClick={this.onChallengeButtonClicked}>Start</button>
```

3. Event handler function can detect which button item was clicked by accessing the event parameter:

```
onChallengeButtonClicked: function(event) {
    item = event.currentTarget.item;
    window.location.href = item.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var myCustomValue = "testing this out";
        return (
            <h1 onClick={this.props.customEvent.bind(this, myCustomValue)}>Testing child click function</h1>
        )
    }
});

var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    customEvent: function (value) {
        // do something wtih value
        alert("you passed " + value);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <ChildComponent customEvent={this.customEvent} />  
        )
    }
});

React.render(
    <ParentComponent customEvent={this.customEvent} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
)
```

Comment: I understand this way, but suppose i want to pass a value to the the event how would i do it ?

Comment: i updated my answer with a full example of how you can pass values from a child to the parent during an event.

Comment: Thanks, I actually decided to use a Link instead but I am gonna need this as well. Will test and comment how it goes